# Turn off optimization in Verilog synthesis

Tags: optimization, verilog, synthesis

I am using genus cadence as a synthesis tool. I have been trying to fasten my project to work at 1GHz . That’s why, I use some multiplexers instead of having complex gates.  Even though, I define multiplexer as a module and synthesis tool understands it is multiplexer, after synthesis, it ignores mux and makes optimization. But then the speed is unsufficient. So ;
- How to turn off optimization?
- If I can’t, how to force synthesis tool to use my gates?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use Mux, use basic gate to infer your desired circuitry. That would preferably give good fmax

Comment: Hi Mr.Darji, The article that I reference, use Muxs to make design faster. That's why I prefer mux. If I can't turn off optimization, how can I set up first priority of optimization is speed not the area? For example, I use -retime command. Can you recommend anything else? Thanks.